Audio input and output not working as soon as microphone is active
I have a very strange issue with Bluetooth headsets / earbuds that started recently. I can connect them fine and as long as only the audio is active, it works fine. But as soon as the microphone is active, neither input nor output are working.
I've tested by putting on some music in the background via YouTube, output set to my Bluetooth earbuds/headset. When I go into System Settings -> Sound, the music keeps playing. As soon as I switch the settings from Output to Input, I can no longer hear the music (the YouTube video keeps playing). When I speak into the microphone, the Input level indicator doesn't show any activity, so it's not getting any input as well. The same thing happens with a Slack call. To summarize: As soon as the active mic indicator is visible, I'm getting no audio input or output.
I've tested this with two different Bluetooth devices, both of which work when connected to my phone, so it's not the device itself.
Tried turning Bluetooth on and off again, forgetting the devices and pairing them again, restarting the computer, clearing the NVRAM (nvram -c), nothing works.
Any ideas?
Mac Mini 2018, Sonoma 14.5
